# How to create token using Hmac in Node js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I am trying to convert Java code to Node js to generate token using Hmac.
Java code-

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(mysecret.getBytes("UTF-8","HmacSHA256")
mac.init(key)
byte[] hash = mac.doFinal(texttoEncode.getBytes(UTF-8))
```

Can anyone please suggest what will be its Javascript /node js equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `crypto` built-in module provides [`createHmac`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhmac_algorithm_key_options) method with the following signature:

```
crypto.createHmac(algorithm, key[, options])
```

To create a token:

```
const Crypto = require('crypto');

const token = Crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'a secret').update('data').digest('hex');

console.log(token); // 5da263f0f0ee86707c7c3f590d20066b7107e5ac70a41560926fa634bc78b137
```

Comment: Hi Adam, In Java code they are passing bytes array to dofinal, but in createhmac update we can only pass string. And the output is not same when I am passing string in update function

Comment: @bhanu, `update` accept a `BinaryLike` argument. You can create that DS using [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Comment: yeah, Crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'a secret').update('data').digest('hex') will get a string.if want a array , try Crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'a secret').update('data').digest()  @bhanu

Comment: Thanks Adam passing buffer fixed the issue.